# My Nexus 4 crashes after every app start

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, crashes

I haven't used my Nexus 4 in a while, and all of a sudden all apps crashes on their start up, including the Google Play Store app.

I have tried to upgrade the OS to KitKat (via Settings => About This Phone => System Updates), but it's stuck updating to 4.3; I have a view with "downloading Android 4.3 update" which doesn't progess.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

> com.google.process.gapps has stopped

Comment: added explanation, though this is jus a work around for all aps crashes.

Comment: I see. The update is probably failing for the same reason as everything else. Did it start happening the first time you used the phone after a while?

Comment: yes. after 2-3 month of no use

Comment: Have you rooted flashed ROMs etc...